# how to show keyboard using ADB command?

Tags: android, adb, android-softkeyboard

I know you can use the function below in java:

```
public static void showKeyboard(EditText mEtSearch, Context context) {
    mEtSearch.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
}
```

but how to get the same effect using the adb command.

Comment: What I need is a way to use the adb command.

Comment: In what context do you want the keyboard (it should be associated with some other app)? If you want to type in some text you can use the `input` command from the adb.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

**Show keyboard**

`adb shell input keyevent 108` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_BUTTON_START)

**Hide keyboard**

`adb shell input keyevent 111`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_ESCAPE

Note: An `EditText` must be in focus for the keyboard to show.

You can check out all the `KeyEvent` on [AOSP](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java?q=KeyEvent&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject)